# How to assign values randomly based on a percentage in SAS?

Tags: variables, statistics, sas

This question pertains to SAS. I need to generate a variable randomly, let's call it "species," for which 60% of the cases are 1's and the remaining 40% of cases are 0's. There are 15,000 cases of x_1 (where x_1 is a random, uniformly distributed variable) which need assignment of either 1 or 0. It's got to be generated with an if-then-do statement, right? So far, I have:

```
data species_list;
    set work.species_list;
    if x_1 <= 0.6 then do;
        Species = 1;
    end;
    else if x_1 > 0.6 then do;
        Species = 0;
    end;
run;
```

This part is easy enough. But, I need the 1's and 0's to be randomly assigned to the 15,000 cases, not based on some inequality.

Answer (score 2):

If `x_1` is a random, uniformly distributed variable, then this inequality does distribute them 'randomly' (as much as can be done with a computer, anyway).

From what I recall, your inequality will work, more or less.  It's not perfect; most likely your random number has a lower bound of 0 and an upper bound of 0.999999, so it's not quite going to give *perfect* 60/40 split, though with 15000 you probably will see a reasonably close match.

A somewhat better way is to use `proc surveyselect`.  This doesn't require your `x_1` variable.

```
proc surveyselect data=species_list out=species_out samprate=0.6 outall seed=12345;
run;
```

That would sample 60% and give them a 1, and the remaining 40% would be a 0.  Easy as pie.

Comment: Right. The inequality was not perfect, but it suffices for a large amount of cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to produce a random variable in SAS you can use the `rand` function.

You could use:

```
Species = ifn(rand("uniform") <= 0.6, 1, 0);
```

or:

```
x_1 = rand("uniform");
if x_1 <= 0.6 then Species = 1;
else Species = 0;
```

Depending on which one is more understandable to you.

- [`rand(dist [, parameters])`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001466748.htm) produces a random number generated from one of several distributions.
- [`ifn(condition, trueValue, falseValue)`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002604573.htm) will return its second or third (numeric) argument depending on whether the condition evaluates to true or false.
- It is not necessary to wrap your conditional statements in [`do; end;`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000202239.htm) if you only want to run one statement.
- If you want reproducable results you can provide a seed to the PRNG with [`call streaminit`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001466799.htm).

Comment: `call streaminit`. (You linked to the right page, just mistyped here.)

Comment: Thanks Joe, quite a big typo really. (`proc setinit` to `call streaminit`)

Comment: So, assuming that x_1 is a random uniformly distributed variable allows that this sampling based on percentages is random... Ok. Thanks!